# Can not get Image on web page using Imagemagick using codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, smarty

Hi I am new at using codeigniter framework. I am trying to upload the image with the help of imagemagick on my web Page(Wamp Server), but when i try to upload it , it shows in admin panel but it does not show in my web page. I do not know how to use image with the help of imagemagick. Please Help .

```
<li>
   <div class="slider-list">
      <div class="slider-img new-height-dev">
      <%assign var=category_image value=$this->general->getGeneratedImage('category_master',$category_data[i].vImage,'','1','Yes','','category_image_size')%>
      <a href="<%$this->general->getProjectLandingUrl($category_data[i])%>" title="<%$category_data[i].vCategoryName%>">
        <img src="<%$category_image%>" alt="<%$category_data[i].vCategoryName%>" title="<%$category_data[i].vCategoryName%>"/>
      </a>
      </div>
   <div class="slider-title" title="<%$category_data[i].vCategoryName%>">
      <a href="<%$this->general->getProjectLandingUrl($category_data[i])%>">
                                        <%$category_data[i].vCategoryName%>
      </a>
   </div>
   </div>
</li>
```

Comment: in your src why not try `src=<?php echo base_url('image_location'.'/'.$category_image);?>` make sure you auto load your  url helper I do not know why you have <% should be <?php I think?

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I can not use core php code in my project . It is a smarty engine page.